# Carousel onmouseover and onmouseout does not work

Tags: javascript, html, css, dom-events

I am practising Javascript. I made an images carousel. My carousel slide works fine. To run the slide I used `setinterval`. When user will hover over the image, I want to stop the slide and when it will hover out then slide will start where it pause. For that I used `clearinterval`. When I `onmouseover` then `onmouseout` my carousel behave weird. Seems like my logic does not work. I don't know how to do that.

```js
const images = document.getElementById('imgs')
const allImages = document.querySelectorAll('#imgs img')
let index = 0;
function run() {
 
  index++;
  if (index > allImages.length - 1) {
    index = 0
  }

  imgs.style.transform = `translateX(${-index * 500}px)`
}

setInterval(run, 2000);

images.onmouseover = () => {
  console.log('In');
  clearInterval(run) + 1
}
images.onmouseout = () => {
  console.log('Out');
  setInterval(run, 2000);
}
```

```css
*{
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

body {
  margin: 0;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  min-height: 100vh;
}

.carousel {
  overflow: hidden;
  width: 500px;
  height: 500px;
  box-shadow: 2px 2px 5px rgba(0, 0, 0, .3);
}

.image-container {
  display: flex;
 transition: transform 300ms linear;
 transform: translateX(0);
}

img {
  width:500px;
  height: 500px;
  object-fit: cover;
}
```

```html
 <div class="carousel">
    <div class="image-container" id="imgs" >
      <img src="https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1599736375341-51b0a848f3c7?ixlib=rb-1.2.1&ixid=eyJhcHBfaWQiOjEyMDd9&auto=format&fit=crop&w=800&q=60" alt="">
      <img src="https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1516026672322-bc52d61a55d5?ixlib=rb-1.2.1&ixid=eyJhcHBfaWQiOjEyMDd9&auto=format&fit=crop&w=800&q=60" alt="">
      <img src="https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1573081586928-127ecc7948b0?ixlib=rb-1.2.1&ixid=eyJhcHBfaWQiOjEyMDd9&auto=format&fit=crop&w=800&q=60" alt="">
      <img src="https://images.unsplash.com/flagged/photo-1572850005109-f4ac7529bf9f?ixlib=rb-1.2.1&ixid=eyJhcHBfaWQiOjEyMDd9&auto=format&fit=crop&w=800&q=60" alt="">
    </div>
  </div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You made a mistake with the interval.
To be able to clear the interval in the onmouseover event, you need to assign it to a variable

```
var x = setInterval(run, 2000);
```

then you pass the variable to the *clearInterval* method.

```
clearInterval(x)
```

then onmouseout you set again the interval

```
x = setInterval(run, 2000);
```

Final code would look like this:

```
var x = setInterval(run, 2000);

images.onmouseover = () => {
  console.log('In');
  clearInterval(x) + 1
}
images.onmouseout = () => {
  console.log('Out');
  x = setInterval(run, 2000);
}
```

Comment: Thanks a lot @Nikko. As I mentioned i am beginner level :). I have couple questions to you: 
1. `why you assign to variable?` 2. `why in clearinterval you added + 1`, 3. `since x = setInterval(run, 2000); then why not just put x in onmouseout`

Comment: You're welcome @krisna.  To answer your question.
1. You need to assign it to a variable because you will be using it later for the clearInterval.
2. Actually, you leave out the "+ 1", I just copied it from your code.
3. It's because clearInterval clears the timer so you need to set it again.